# How to integrate $\int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{x^{2}-1}{x})}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{x^{2}-1}{x})}{x} dx$$
I tried a couple of thing such as

- integration by parts by letting $\frac{1}{x}$ as an intigrable function but got 
  $$-\int_{1/2}^{2}\cos(x-\frac{1}{x})*(1+\frac{1}{x^2})*\ln{x}$$
  I don't know how to proceed further please help

Comment: If you substitute $u=\frac{1}{x}$, you get the same integral, but with a minus sign. So the integral is $0$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$I=\int_{\frac12}^{2}\frac{\color{blue}{\sin\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)}}{x} dx$$
$$\text{let}\  x=\frac{1}{t}\rightarrow dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$$
$$I=\int^{\frac12}_2 \frac{\sin\left(\frac1{t}-t\right)}{\frac{1}{t}}\frac{-dt}{t^2}=\int_{\frac12}^2\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{t}-t\right)}{t}dt\overset{t=x}=-\int_{\frac12}^2\frac{\color{red}{\sin\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)}}{x}dx$$
Thus, if we add with the initial integral we get: $$2I=\int_{\frac12}^2\frac{\overset{=0}{\color{blue}{\sin\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)}-\color{red}{\sin\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)}}}{x}dx=0\Rightarrow I=0$$